# run python script in the background

Tags: python

I wrote a Python script to run several NS-3 simulations with different seeds and different node counts.
My script calls `./waf --run=<scenario_name>` then executes 10 seeds, change node count and execute 10 more seeds, and so on.

The problem is that after I call my script, I ask the user for an input (which scenario to run). Because of that `raw_input` call, I couldn't use `nohup myScript.py &`. I also tried `CTRL + Z`, `bg`, and `disown`. But that didn't work either.

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
import glob

scenario = raw_input("Type scenario (foo or bar): ")
if scenario == 'foo':
    wafString = './waf --run "scratch/test-foo --nodeCount='

elif scenario == 'bar':
    wafString = './waf --run "scratch/test-bar --nodeCount='

else:
    print ("Wrong input!")

ns3Global = 'NS_GLOBAL_VALUE="RngRun='    
numbers = [25, 50, 100] # number of nodes

for nodeCount in numbers:
   for rngRun in range(1,11):
       myArgument =  ns3Global + str(rngRun) + '" ' + wafString + str(nodeCount) + '" '

       print "*** Running experiment with " + str(nodeCount) + \
             " nodes and random seed " + str(rngRun) + "\n"
       subprocess.call(myArgument, shell=True)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not write 2 scripts? The first script will ask the user for the input, then start the second script (with the scenario parameter) in the background and terminate itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess.Popen(...` instead of `subprocess.call(`

```
p = subprocess.Popen(myArgument)
```

Avoid to use `shell=True`  if `ns3Global` don't need it.

> **Python 3.6 » Documentation »**  [17.5. subprocess — Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)
>   Execute a child program in a new process.

Comment: I did what the instructions said about using `Popen` and parsing the command as a list, but got an `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Have you watched the **Note about shlex.split()** you see below on the linked page?

Comment: Yes. I'm using `args = shlex.split(myArgument )` and then `p = subprocess.Popen(args)`

Comment: @John: Please add the output of `print(args)` and your Python Version to your Question.

Comment: `args = ['NS_GLOBAL_VALUE=RngRun=1', './waf', '--run', 'scratch/test-foo --nodeCount=25']`
I'm using python 2.7

Comment: @John: The **first** Parameter have to be the **executable**. You should arrange the Parameter same as executing it at the command shell prompt. I assume `./waf` is the Executable. Whatever `'NS_GLOBAL_VALUE=RngRun=1` are be, looks not as a _common_ Parameter.