# Can you secretly run a python file?

Tags: python

I couldn't find any answers to this question posted by others, so here is my question:

**Is it possible to have a python program run without displaying the code or opening any windows?** This file does not print anything, so the shell file or code opening up is a distraction. Should I just try to convert it into a .exe file? And if there is a way to run a python file without opening any window, would it work only on PC or also on a mac?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure what you mean. If you execute a .py file without a GUI it does just this.

Comment: Yes, you can run a python file without opening any window on any/all OSes

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the information. I appreciate it!

Comment: See if this helps.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975624/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh.  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916158/run-python-script-in-the-background

Comment: If you mean for MS-Windows, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cmd do the following...

```
pythonw yourscript.py
```

This can be especially useful when you are doing a desktop notification model